# Replace line breaks using Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

How can I replace all types of line breaks (CR, LF and CrLf) using Regex?

I´ve tried different combinations of "\n" and "\r" but none finds them all.

```
formatedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "\r\n", "[Exp 1]")
```

The following code does the job but it bugs me that I can´t seem to replace the Line Feed using Regexp.

```
formatedString = formatedString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "[Environment.NewLine]") ' Equals CR
formatedString = formatedString.Replace(ControlChars.CrLf, "[ControlChars.CrLf]") ' CR and LF
formatedString = formatedString.Replace(ControlChars.Cr, "[ControlChars.Cr]") ' Carriage Return (CR)
formatedString = formatedString.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, "[ControlChars.Lf]") ' Line Feed (LF)
```

All advices are most welcome! :)

Comment: My best expression so far is; "(\r\n|\n|\r)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\r`, `\n` and `\r\n` should cover all cases of linebreaks. `\n\r` is not used by any system (that I know of...)

In VB, if not using regexes, you could replace all:

```
VbCr
VbLf
VbCrLf
```

with whatever line ending you prefer (obviously you can omit the preferred one from the list of "newline/cr" characters you replace)

Comment: Thanks, that was some kind of typo :P

Comment: So, did the solution work? Could you please mark it as an answer if the solution worked? Or was it just a typo in your post here?

Comment: Your post inspired me to write the expression "(\r\n|\n|\r)" so I´ll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (code not tested) -

```
formatedString  = Regex.Replace(text, "\r\n", "[Exp 1]", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested and working:

```
dim source = String.Concat("Some string", VbLf, "with", VbCr, "line", VbCrLf, "breaks")
dim result = Regex.Replace(source, "[\r\n]", " ")
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/BcMbhZ

Answer (score 0):

The sample from @ipr101 takes 90%. But in case of CrLf, it creates 2 x " " instead of 1 x " ".
Therefore, I'd recommend following script:

```vb
Dim source = String.Concat("Some string", vbLf, "with", vbCr, "line", vbCrLf, "breaks")
Dim result = Regex.Replace(source, "(?:\r\n|\r|\n)", " ")
```

If you like to preserve the line breaks and just add a prefix of space chars to each line, you can also use:

```vb
Dim source = String.Concat("Some string", vbLf, "with", vbCr, "line", vbCrLf, "breaks")
Dim result = Regex.Replace(source, "(?:\r\n|\r|\n)", "$0   ")
```