# Display all SSRS report field values without line breaks

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with a dataset that I cannot modify.  I can only change the report's format.

I am trying to figure out how to have one of the reports fields display its many values inline in a list or csv fashion.  Right now it prints a value and does a line break, then the next value and another line break, and so on...  I would like my values to print without the line breaks.

I've tried using the Replace function in an expression (replace vbcrlf with ", ") with no success...

Comment: Why can't you change the dataset?

Comment: Also: what is your current report structure? What controls are you using for the current layout?

Comment: I can't change the dataset because it's a report embedded in a vendor-provided product.  I am only allowed to change the layout/format of the report.
I can use any appropriate control.  It's currently a textbox in a tablix.

Answer (score 1):

You're not quite providing enough information to reliably answer the question. Most likely, your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10997770/419956), and [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11057590/419956) will answer your question as well. The basics are:

1. Create a multi-value parameter `@MyParameter`
2. Set the default values for the parameter to be retrieved from your dataset
3. In your textbox use the expression `=Join(Parameters!MyParameter.Value, ", ")`

Same disclaimer holds here as well: if there are a lot of values this solution may not work very well.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want an expression to remove the line feed characters in your source data so that it prints on one line. You'll probably need a bit of trial and error to work our what the characters actually are but you probably want to start with replacing:

vbCrLf

vbLf

vbCr

More on replacing line breaks in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160820/replace-line-breaks-using-regex)

You could create a Code function in the report to do the replacing, similar to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929793/ssrs-2008-multi-line-data-displaying-as-one-line-in-report).